# Bitwise left shifting of integer by more than 31 times

Tags: c

```
main()
{
   int i=-1,j=32,k;
   k=i<<j;
   printf("i=%d j=%d k=%d\n",i,j,k);
}
```

output:

```
i=-1 j=32,k=-1
```

If I am taking j=33 then `k=-2` and if j=34 then k=-4.its repeating after 32 times left shift i.e  if j=64,k becomes -1 and if j=65 then k=-2.but logically bit should be lost i.e output is 0.what is happening here.

Sorry for asking such a question. I am beginner so I'm unable to understand what the compiler does here. Can you explain?

Comment: The typical behaviour (although not standardized) that I see is that it results in a shift modulo 32.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot count on getting a meaningful result when shifting a value by an amount equal to or greater than its size. From the standard:

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or
>   equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.